# Minimization of quadratic function

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

For the quadratic function $\mathcal{E}(\textbf{w}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i} - \textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_{i})^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\textbf{w} \|_{2}^{2}$, I was trying to obtain the $\hat{\textbf{w}}$ that minimizes it. So,

$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{E}(\textbf{w})}{\partial\textbf{w}} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i} - \textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_{i})(-\textbf{x}_{i})+\lambda\textbf{w} = 0
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}d_{i}\textbf{x}_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_{i})\textbf{x}_{i} +\lambda\mathbb{I}\textbf{w}
$$
At this point, I do not know how to put the right side on the form: $(R+\lambda\mathbb{I})\textbf{w}$, where $R$ is the cross correlation matrix and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Any constraints concerning $\textbf{w}$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo There are no constraints concerning **w**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_{i})\textbf{x}_{i}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \textbf{x}_i\textbf{x}_i^T\right)\textbf{w} = R\textbf{w}
$$

then

$$
\textbf{w} =\left(R+\lambda\mathbb{I}\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}d_{i}\textbf{x}_{i}
$$

Comment: I was thinking that this would be the right answer, but the book says the correlation matrix is $\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{i}x_{j}^T$. The book is The Third Edition of Neural Networks and Learning Machines by Simon Haykin, and this definition is found in page 75.

Comment: The result depicted in page 75 of Neural Networks and Learning Machines by Simon Haykin, is wrong.

Comment: I found that there is a note from professor Zoya that is also using your solution: https://web.mit.edu/zoya/www/docs.html. So I think you are right and the books has an error.